# Find if any QTips are visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have a window interval that runs code every 5 seconds. However,this code can potentially remove and recreate certain elements that might be showing the user a QTip.

Is there a way to find if there is a QTip that is visible using JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can test it by using:

```
if($('.qtip:visible').length > 0)
```

Comment: How can it be checked on a particular element? @robin

Comment: Not sure to understand your question, but you can replace the .qtip selector by the one you want, so that you can check every element you want